# Get list style types in MS Word add-in Javascript APIs

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am trying to use the Word add-in Javascript APIs to print the level and style type of lists in a document.

I am using the following code:

```
    Word.run(function (context) {

        var range = context.document.getSelection();
        var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs.load("items");
        var lists = [];
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++) {
                    if (paragraphs.items[i].isListItem) {
                        lists.push(paragraphs.items[i].listItem.load(['level', 'listString']));
                    }
                }
            })
            .then(context.sync)
            .then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
                    range.insertText(lists[i].level.toString(), "End");
                }
            }).then(context.sync)

    })
```

This gives the level of the lists correctly but `listString` gives the list number as it is instead of its type i.e For `1. This is a list item`, it will return `1.`.
I tried using `levelTypes` in the `Word.List` class but it only returns Number, Bullet or Picture. I want specific types like "Roman" | "Arabic" | "Letter" | "Solid" | "Hollow" etc...

There are APIs `setLevelBullet` and `setLevelNumbering` to set these values but couldn't find any that allows to read.

I tried converting it to OOXML but it too doesn't give the types of list style used.

I am able to do this in python using pypandoc library. It converts the doc into HTML and then I can parse the ul and ol tags to find their types. Is there some way to do this in Word Add-in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the Word object models (COM or JavaScript) provide this information. Word is not HTML and doesn't "think" in terms of `ol`/`ul` - all lists are just (9-level) lists, each level having a specific set of characters (or none) that "prefix" the paragraph.

It would be necessary to write your own code to analyse the `listString`, or use a library that does this. Possibly based on the Unicode value.

Answer (score 0):

*I tried converting it to OOXML but it too doesn't give the types of list style used.*

OOXML has all the information you need for this. Document.xml has the listId in the paragraph that is marked as listItem. It references to the numbering-xml file that has the information on a specific list and their formatting on each level. ListId:s point to the abstract block in the end of numbering file and that points to the actual formatting definition.

Not 100% sure that can you also point to the formatting with paragraph styleId.